# JavaScript ReferenceError function is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have the following function that should toggle a div `js-show-more-content`

```
<div class="season-list" id="js-show-more-container">
```

when the user clicks the class with `show-more` and executes just fine in the dev console, but returning `Uncaught ReferenceError: showMore is not defined at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick`

[image: browser error]

when running from the external js file. I've also tried `SeriesDetail.showMore` for the onClick.

```
showMore() {
const episodes = document.getElementById("js-show-more-container");
  if(episodes) {
    episodes.style.display = episodes.style.display == "flex" ? "none" : "flex";
  }
}

<p class="show-more" onclick="showMore('js-show-more-container')">SHOW MORE</p>
```

Here's the external js file for context:

```
const SeriesDetail = {
  seasonItems: undefined,
  keyContainer: undefined,
  keyItems: undefined,

  bindEvents () {
    this.keyContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const target = e.target
      const number = (target.dataset && target.dataset.seasonNum) || 1
      this.setSeason(number)
    })
  },

  init () {
    this.keyContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('js-season-key-items')[0]

    const keyItems = this.keyContainer.querySelectorAll('.js-season-key')
    this.keyItems = [...keyItems]

    const seasonItems = document.getElementsByClassName('js-season-list-item')
    this.seasonItems = [...seasonItems]

    const seasonNum = this.getQuery('season') || 1

    this.setSeason(seasonNum)
    this.bindEvents()

    return this
  },

  setSeason (number) {
    this.seasonItems.map(s => {
      s.style.display = s.id === `season-${number}`
        ? 'block'
        : 'none'
    })
  },

  showMore() {
    const episodes = document.getElementById("js-show-more-container");
    if(episodes) {
      episodes.style.display = episodes.style.display == "flex" ? "none" : "flex";
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  SeriesDetail.init()
})
```

Comment: Briefly scanning over your code it looks like you have declared showMore as a function with no arguments but you are trying to pass it a string when you call it on the onClick

Comment: I was trying to specify the div to toggle, but even without passing the div, it should be able to just run the `showMore` function and apply the styling based on the javascript within the function. I believe the main issue is why am I getting an error that that `showMore` function is not defined?

Comment: `showMore` is a property of `SeriesDetail`, not a global variable. You'd want `SeriesDetail.showMore(...)`.

Comment: @FelixKling - I've tried that as well, but it returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: SeriesDetail is not defined at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick`

Comment: Then your JavaScript file doesn’t load.

Comment: It is though, because everything else is functioning properly. I'm thinking it's the showMore not getting initialized properly, but not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: The error means that `SeriesDetail` does not exist at the moment the `onClick` handler is executed. That's all we can say.

Comment: I think it might not be initialized before its being clicked, but I've used `this.showMore()` in the init and bind functions with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="season-list" id="js-show-more-container">
<p class="show-more" onclick="SeriesDetail.showMore('js-show-more-container')">SHOW MORE</p>
</div>
```

Your all code are right.You need to call showMore function with the help of class only like mentioned above.

Comment: So, as I mentioned in the comments earlier, using `SeriesDetail.showMore('js-show-more-container`)` returns the error: `3158780?season=1:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: SeriesDetail is not defined
    at HTMLParagraphElement.onclick`. Also, the `season-list` class doesn't wrap the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution below. I needed to set an initial undefined state for the trigger, correctly bind the event listener for the trigger, initialize the trigger in the DOM, and align that based on the currently selected div.

```
const SeriesDetail = {
  showMoreTrigger: undefined,

  bindEvents () {
    this.showMoreTrigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.showMore();
    });
  },

  init () {
    this.showMoreTrigger = document.getElementsByClassName('js-show-more-trigger')[0]
    this.setSeason(seasonNum)
    this.bindEvents()

    return this
  },

  showMore() {
    let seasons = document.getElementByClassName("js-season-list-more");
    seasons = [...seasons]
    let season = seasons.find(s => {
      const number = s.dataset.seasonNumber
      return this.activeSeason === number
    })
    if(episodes) {
      episodes.style.display = episodes.style.display == "flex" ? "none" : "flex";
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  SeriesDetail.init()
})
```

Also, removed the onclick event from the actual trigger, using the event listener to handle the click event:

```
span(class="js-show-more-trigger") SHOW MORE
```